# postgres create database; column 'dataconfig' does not exist

Tags: macos, postgresql

I've just installed PgAdmin 8.4 on an OSX Lion 10.7.3 pc with Postgres 9.1 installed.
When I try to add a database, I get an error message:
"Error: column 'dataconfig' does not exist"
Does it mean a mismatch between client and server versions?  I couldn't find a later PgAdmin version.

Comment: You are confusing [pgAdmin](http://pgadmin.org/) (the GUI, latest version 1.14.1) with [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/) (the database management system, latest version 9.1). Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you mean the pgAdmin version that is bundled with some versions of postgresql 8.4 then that version is to old. It is inspecting the system catalogs to figure out the database lay-out but it doesn't support the 9.1 version of the system catalogue. If you used the one click installer you can use the bundled pgadmin. You can find it in Applications/PostgreSQL 9.1/pgAdmin III.app

Otherwise download the latest from [here](http://pgadmin.org/download/macosx.php)

Answer (score 1):

Try pgadmin3-1.16.1 - it works. I've tried with many other versions (for example pgadmin3-1.8.3 and pgadmin3-1.16.0), but without success.